# Reuse weights of a function in keras

Tags: keras, tensorflow2.0

I have a function called `block`

```
from tensorflow.keras import layers
from tensorflow.keras.initializers import glorot_uniform

def block(X, classes):
    X = layers.Conv2D(filters = 3, kernel_size = (1, 1), strides = (1,1), name = 'a', kernel_initializer = glorot_uniform())(X)
    X = layers.Activation('relu')(X)

    X = layers.Flatten()(X)
    X = layers.Dense(classes, activation='linear', name='fc', kernel_initializer = glorot_uniform())(X)
    return X
```

`block` is a neural network module. I would like to reuse the weights of `block` for several inputs. For example, say I have two inputs: `input1`, `input2`. How would I pass them through `block` such that the weights are reused again for `input2`. The below code does not work as it initializes a new set of weights for `B`.

```
input1 = layers.Input((64, 64, 3))
input2 = layers.Input((64, 64, 3))

A = block(input1, 10)
B = block(input2, 10)

print(A)
print(B)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One option of reusing is to use a shared model. We can create a separate model out of `block()`, which we can re-use anytime we want.

```
import tensorflow as tf

from tensorflow.keras import layers
from tensorflow.keras import models
from tensorflow.keras.initializers import glorot_uniform

# this is my block
def block(X, classes):
    X = layers.Conv2D(filters = 3, kernel_size = (1, 1), strides = (1,1), kernel_initializer = glorot_uniform())(X)
    X = layers.Activation('relu')(X)

    X = layers.Flatten()(X)
    X = layers.Dense(classes, activation='linear', kernel_initializer = glorot_uniform())(X)
    return X


# block model

ip_base = layers.Input((64, 64, 3)) # decide on it
op = block(ip_base, 3)
block_model = models.Model(ip_base, op)

block_model_weights = block_model.get_weights()  # we can save this as pickle and later load for another model
print(block_model_weights)

# now we can save/re-use the weight of this model anytime we want
# secondary

input1 = layers.Input((64, 64, 3))
input2 = layers.Input((64, 64, 3))

A = block_model(input1)
B = block_model(input2)

model = models.Model([input1, input2], [A, B])

tf.keras.utils.plot_model(
    model)
```

Out:

```
[array([[[[ 0.07414746, -0.41065478, -0.5521915 ],
         [-0.6518545 ,  0.09209108,  0.9978211 ],
         [ 0.8638036 ,  0.5552795 ,  0.2620473 ]]]], dtype=float32), array([0., 0., 0.], dtype=float32), array([[-0.02172941,  0.00599053,  0.00549869],
       [-0.01580501, -0.01591844,  0.0140271 ],
       [ 0.0102962 ,  0.01141792, -0.00722483],
       ...,
       [ 0.00119783,  0.0168376 , -0.00014478],
       [ 0.00626496, -0.0100358 ,  0.01791514],
       [-0.00650628, -0.00537593,  0.00106668]], dtype=float32), array([0., 0., 0.], dtype=float32)]
```

[image]

As you can see if we create a `Model` object out of the base and then pass any input through it, the weights will be shared.

If we want to load a pre-trained `block` model and then use its previous weight and pass one of our input, we can simply do this.

```
# save the weights of the block model

weights = np.array(block_model.get_weights())

np.save('block_weights.npy', weights, allow_pickle = True)

# now we create another new block model
# block model

ip_base = layers.Input((64, 64, 3)) # decide on it
op = block(ip_base, 3)
new_block_model = models.Model(ip_base, op)

# currently it's randomly initialized but we can take the previous weights and load that in the current model

# load weight

old_weights = np.load('block_weights.npy', allow_pickle = True)

new_block_model.set_weights( old_weights )

# compare all of the weights

print(weights)
print('---------------')
print(old_weights)
print('---------------')
print(new_block_model.get_weights())
```

Out:

```
[array([[[[ 0.38135457, -0.28602505,  0.6248524 ],
         [-0.10373783,  0.20868587, -0.0295043 ],
         [ 0.073596  , -0.85106397,  0.86780167]]]], dtype=float32)
 array([0., 0., 0.], dtype=float32)
 array([[-0.00512073,  0.00298601,  0.015619  ],
       [ 0.01500274,  0.01736909, -0.0106204 ],
       [ 0.00690563,  0.00548493,  0.00449893],
       ...,
       [-0.00202469, -0.00226198,  0.0212799 ],
       [-0.01203138, -0.00065516, -0.01211848],
       [-0.01238732, -0.00368575,  0.02146613]], dtype=float32)
 array([0., 0., 0.], dtype=float32)]
---------------
[array([[[[ 0.38135457, -0.28602505,  0.6248524 ],
         [-0.10373783,  0.20868587, -0.0295043 ],
         [ 0.073596  , -0.85106397,  0.86780167]]]], dtype=float32)
 array([0., 0., 0.], dtype=float32)
 array([[-0.00512073,  0.00298601,  0.015619  ],
       [ 0.01500274,  0.01736909, -0.0106204 ],
       [ 0.00690563,  0.00548493,  0.00449893],
       ...,
       [-0.00202469, -0.00226198,  0.0212799 ],
       [-0.01203138, -0.00065516, -0.01211848],
       [-0.01238732, -0.00368575,  0.02146613]], dtype=float32)
 array([0., 0., 0.], dtype=float32)]
---------------
[array([[[[ 0.38135457, -0.28602505,  0.6248524 ],
         [-0.10373783,  0.20868587, -0.0295043 ],
         [ 0.073596  , -0.85106397,  0.86780167]]]], dtype=float32), array([0., 0., 0.], dtype=float32), array([[-0.00512073,  0.00298601,  0.015619  ],
       [ 0.01500274,  0.01736909, -0.0106204 ],
       [ 0.00690563,  0.00548493,  0.00449893],
       ...,
       [-0.00202469, -0.00226198,  0.0212799 ],
       [-0.01203138, -0.00065516, -0.01211848],
       [-0.01238732, -0.00368575,  0.02146613]], dtype=float32), array([0., 0., 0.], dtype=float32)]
```

Answer (score 0):

It might help if you either make `block` be a class that inherits from `tf.keras.Model` or change it so that it returns a `Sequential` model with all of your desired layers. Currently, it appears you aren't saving your weights anywhere.

For instance:

```
A = tf.keras.Sequential([
    # ... your layers
])

B = tf.keras.Sequential([
    # ... your layers
])


# Or use:

def block(params):
    model = tf.keras.Sequential([
        # ... your layers with params
    ])
    return model

A = block(params)
B = block(params)

# Or use

class block(tf.keras.Model):
  def __init__(self, params):
    super(block, self).__init__()
    self.layer1 = # ... first layer
    # ... your layers

  def call(self, inputs):
    X = self.layer1(inputs)
    # ... the rest of your layers
    return X
```

You then should be able to get layer weights like so `A.layers[layer_number].get_weights()` and set weights with `B.layers[layer_number].set_weights([np_weight_arr])`.

Additionally, I'm aware that some individual layers accept a `weights` parameter, although I'd have to double check that it works for all layers you mentioned. I know for instance you can do something like `layers.Embedding(vocab_size+1, emb_dim, weights=[embedding_matrix], input_length=maxlength)`, where `embedding_matrix` is a numpy array.

Lastly, if you can just reuse A, that would be the simplest solution.